# Ребус: VOLVO+FIAT=MOTOR

Tags: pascal

Ребус: VOLVO+FIAT=MOTOR. Каждая буква – это цифра, разным буквам соответствуют разные цифры. Необходимо заменить буквы цифрами так, чтобы получилось верное равенство. Найти все решения (если есть несколько ). ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ТИП «МНОЖЕСТВО».

помогите, пожалуйста отыскать ошибку [в коде](https://pastebin.com/ZTRHVqMV) (или предложите свой вариант решения)

```
Program Rebus;// VOLVO + FIAT= MOTOR
Type
  MN = set of 0..9;
Var
  f,i,a,t,v,o,l,m,r : 0..9;
  S1, S2, S3 : MN;{для хранения цифр каждого из чисел}
  sum,motor:longint;
Begin
  S1 := [ ];
  S2 := [ ];
  s3 := [ ];
  for v := 1 to 9 do
  begin
    S1 := S1+[v];
    for o := 0 to 9 do
      if Not(o in S1) then
      begin
        S1 := S1+[o];
        for l := 0 to 9 do
          if Not (l in S1) then
          begin 
            S1 := S1+[l];                    
            for f:=0 to 9 do 
            begin
              S2 := S2+[f];
                for i :=0 to 9 do
                  if Not(i in S2) then
                  begin
                    S2 := S2+[i];
                    for a := 0 to 9 do
                      if Not (a in S2) then
                      begin 
                        S2 := S2+[a];      
                          for t:=0 to 9 do
                            if Not (t in S2) then
                              begin
                                s2:=s2+[t];
                                for m:=1 to 9 do 
                                begin
                                  S3 := S3+[m];                  
                                  for r:=0 to 9 do
                                    if Not (r in S3) then
                                    begin
                                      s3:=s3+[r];              
                                      sum:=10000*v+1000*(o+f)+100*(l+i)+10*(v+a)+(o+t);
                                      motor:=10000*m+1000*o+100*t+10*o+r;
                                      if sum=motor then
                                        if (s1*s2=[ ]) and (s2*s3=[t])and (s1*s3=[o])then
                                          writeln(v,o,l,v,o,'+',f,i,a,t,'=',m,o,t,o,r);
                                      s3:=s3-[r];
                                    end;
                                    s3:=s3-[m];
                                end;
                                s2:=s2-[t];
                              end;
                        s2:=s2-[a];
                      end;
                    s2:=s2-[i];
                  end;
               s2:=s2-[f];
            end;
            s1:=s1-[l]; 
          end;
          s1:=s1-[o];
      end;
    s1:=s1-[v];
  end;
  Readln;
End.
```

Comment: Программа не может найти ни одного решения, а должна целых 10. Но ошибки не выдает.

Comment: А оно точно есть? Я слышал про загадку "как из слова МУХА сделать слово СЛОН"... но тут ни по числу буквы, ни по набору букв не выходит. Это как со словом "вечность" и набором из 4х кубиков. Вы бы условие подписали в текст вопроса.

Comment: Вот все 10 решений 15615+9743=25358
15715+9643=25358
36736+9825=46561
36836+9725=46561
46346+9821=56167
46846+9321=56167
71571+9642=81213
71671+9542=81213
72472+9651=82123
72672+9451=82123

Comment: Кстати, а почему у тебя 3 сета, когда нужен один?

Comment: Ответ обновлён. Вроде работает.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/1OY1ku

```
program rebus;

var
  v, o, l, f, i, a, t, m, r: 0..9;
  used: set of 0..9;
  volvo, fiat, motor: longint;

begin
  used := [];

  for v := 1 to 9 do if not (v in used) then begin used := used + [v];
  for o := 0 to 9 do if not (o in used) then begin used := used + [o];
  for l := 0 to 9 do if not (l in used) then begin used := used + [l];
  for f := 1 to 9 do if not (f in used) then begin used := used + [f];
  for i := 0 to 9 do if not (i in used) then begin used := used + [i];
  for a := 0 to 9 do if not (a in used) then begin used := used + [a];
  for t := 0 to 9 do if not (t in used) then begin used := used + [t];
  for m := 1 to 9 do if not (m in used) then begin used := used + [m];
  for r := 0 to 9 do if not (r in used) then begin used := used + [r];

  volvo := (((((v)*10+o)*10+l)*10+v)*10+o);
  fiat := ((((f)*10+i)*10+a)*10+t);
  motor := (((((m)*10+o)*10+t)*10+o)*10+r);

  if volvo + fiat = motor then writeln(volvo, '+', fiat, '=', motor);

  used := used - [r] end;
  used := used - [m] end;
  used := used - [t] end;
  used := used - [a] end;
  used := used - [i] end;
  used := used - [f] end;
  used := used - [l] end;
  used := used - [o] end;
  used := used - [v] end;

end.
```

Оно же на javascript:

```js
var v, o, l, f, i, a, t, m, r;
var used = 0;
var volvo, fiat, motor;

for (v=1; v<10; ++v) if (!(used & (1<<v))) { used |= 1<<v;
for (o=0; o<10; ++o) if (!(used & (1<<o))) { used |= 1<<o;
for (l=0; l<10; ++l) if (!(used & (1<<l))) { used |= 1<<l;
for (f=1; f<10; ++f) if (!(used & (1<<f))) { used |= 1<<f;
for (i=0; i<10; ++i) if (!(used & (1<<i))) { used |= 1<<i;
for (a=0; a<10; ++a) if (!(used & (1<<a))) { used |= 1<<a;
for (t=0; t<10; ++t) if (!(used & (1<<t))) { used |= 1<<t;
for (m=1; m<10; ++m) if (!(used & (1<<m))) { used |= 1<<m;
for (r=0; r<10; ++r) if (!(used & (1<<r))) { used |= 1<<r;

volvo = (((((v)*10+o)*10+l)*10+v)*10+o)
fiat = ((((f)*10+i)*10+a)*10+t)
motor = (((((m)*10+o)*10+t)*10+o)*10+r)

if(volvo + fiat === motor) console.log(volvo, fiat, motor)

used ^= 1<<r; }
used ^= 1<<m; }
used ^= 1<<t; }
used ^= 1<<a; }
used ^= 1<<i; }
used ^= 1<<f; }
used ^= 1<<l; }
used ^= 1<<o; }
used ^= 1<<v; }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Код получен вот так:

```js
code = `var v, o, l, f, i, a, t, m, r;
var used = 0;
var volvo, fiat, motor;

` + "volfiatmr".split("").map(c=>
`for (X=0; X<10; ++X) if (!(used & (1<<X))) { used |= 1<<X;
used ^= 1<<X; }`.replace(/X/g, c)).reduceRight((r,x) => x.replace("\n", "\n" + r + "\n"), `
${"volvo,fiat,motor".split(",").map(x => x + " = " + x.replace(/\w+/g, s=>"(".repeat(s.length)+s).replace(/\w/g, "$&)*10+").replace(/\*10\+(?!\w)/g, "")).join("\n")}

if(volvo + fiat === motor) console.log(volvo, fiat, motor)
`
).replace(/([vfm])=0/g, "$1=1")

console.log(code)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

```js
code = `program rebus;

var
  v, o, l, f, i, a, t, m, r: 0..9;
  used: set of 0..9;
  volvo, fiat, motor: longint;

begin
  used := [];

` + "volfiatmr".split("").map(c=>
`  for X := 0 to 9 do if not (X in used) then begin used := used + [X];
  used := used - [X] end;`.replace(/X/g, c)).reduceRight((r,x) => x.replace("\n", "\n" + r + "\n"), `
${"volvo,fiat,motor".split(",").map(x => "  " + x + " := " + x.replace(/\w+/g, s=>"(".repeat(s.length)+s).replace(/\w/g, "$&)*10+").replace(/\*10\+(?!\w)/g, ";")).join("\n")}

  if volvo + fiat = motor then writeln(volvo, '+', fiat, '=', motor);
`
).replace(/([vfm]) := 0/g, "$1 := 1") + `

end.`

console.log(code)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```