# Обобщённый ребус VOLVO+FIAT=MOTOR

Tags: любой-язык

По следам вопроса [Ребус: VOLVO+FIAT=MOTOR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793156/213987).

> Каждая буква – это цифра, разным буквам соответствуют разные цифры.
>   Необходимо заменить буквы цифрами так, чтобы получилось верное
>   равенство. Найти все решения (если есть несколько ).

Задача такая же, но слова могут быть произвольные, а не только именно эти.

Comment: Надо бы придумать критерии и сделать соревнованием.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

var aaa = document.getElementById("a").value;
var bbb = document.getElementById("b").value;
var ccc = document.getElementById("c").value;

var all = (aaa + bbb + ccc).replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
var abc = (aaa.charAt(1) && aaa[0]) + (bbb.charAt(1) && bbb[0]) + (ccc.charAt(1) && ccc[0]);

console.log(`${aaa} + ${bbb} = ${ccc}`);

var code = `(function () {
var ${all.split("")};
var used = 0;
var _${aaa}, _${bbb}, _${ccc};

` + all.split("").map(c=>
`for (X=0; X<10; ++X) if (!(used & (1<<X))) { used |= 1<<X;
used ^= 1<<X; }`.replace(/X/g, c)).reduceRight((r,x) => x.replace("\n", "\n" + r + "\n"), `
${[aaa,bbb,ccc].map(x => `_${x} = ${x.replace(/\w+/g, s=>"(".repeat(s.length)+s).replace(/\w/g, "$&)*10+").replace(/\*10\+(?!\w)/g, "")}`).join("\n")}

if(_${aaa} + _${bbb} === _${ccc}) console.log(_${aaa} + " + " + _${bbb} + " = " + _${ccc})
`
).replace(RegExp(`([${abc}@])=0`, "g"), "$1=1") + `

})()`

//console.log(code);
eval(code);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: calc(100vh - 3em) }
```

```html
<form>
  <input id=a required pattern=[a-z]+ value=volvo>
  +
  <input id=b required pattern=[a-z]+ value=fiat>
  =
  <input id=c required pattern=[a-z]+ value=motor>
  
  <input type=submit value=Solve>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Гм. Когда-то давно писал под свои нужды, умеет немного больше, чем просто арифметика - например, `VOLVO+FIAT=MOTOR**Q!` (в смысле - факториал, возведение в степень, квадратный корень... да даже системы уравнений :) - типа `a+b=c; 2*a+3*b=8` в командной строке. Понимает русские буквы. Сносить два этажа и резать, гм... ну, вы поняли, как в анекдоте - не буду :)

Многопоточность.

Использовал немного модифицированный YACC, так что теперь не знаю, что и давать: YACC'овский файл или С++ :)

Держите C++. Чистить лень :(

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define  NDEBUG

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <locale>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

inline long long ipow(long long x, long long p)
{
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return x;
    long long r = 1;
    while(p)
    {
        if (p&0x1) r*= x;
        x *= x;
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

inline unsigned long long isqrt(unsigned long long x)
{
    unsigned long long x1, g0, g1;
    if (x <= 1) return x;
    int s = 1;
    x1 = x - 1;
    if (x1 > 0xFFFFFFFF) { s = s + 16; x1 >>= 32; }
    if (x1 > 0xFFFF)     { s = s +  8; x1 >>= 16; }
    if (x1 > 0xFF)       { s = s +  4; x1 >>=  8; }
    if (x1 > 0xF)        { s = s +  2; x1 >>=  4; }
    if (x1 > 0x3)        { s = s +  1; }

    g0 = 1ll << s;
    g1 = (g0 +(x>>s)) >> 1;
    while( g1 < g0) {
        g0 = g1;
        g1 = (g0 + (x/g0)) >> 1;
    }
    return g0;
}

long long fact(long long x)
{
    assert(x <= 20);
    static long long vals[21] = {1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    if (vals[x]) return vals[x];
    long long s = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
    {
        s *= i;
        vals[i] = s;
    }
    return s;
}

long long bifact(long long x)
{
    assert(x <= 32);
    static long long vals[33] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    if (vals[x]) return vals[x];
    long long s = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i += 2)
    {
        s *= i;
        vals[i] = s;
    }
    s = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 32; i += 2)
    {
        s *= i;
        vals[i] = s;
    }
    return vals[x];
}



typedef long long ALM_STYPE;
static int alm_parse( void * alm_param );

#define   Number                 257
#define   Wrong                  258
#define   uminus                 259
#define   alm_IntError
#define   alm_clearin  alm_char = -1
#define   alm_errok    alm_errflag = 0
#ifndef   ALM_MAXDEPTH        
#define   ALM_MAXDEPTH           150
#endif
#define   ALM_ERRCODE            256



template< typename RandomAccess, typename Compare >
bool next_kpermutation( RandomAccess first, RandomAccess last,
                       typename std::iterator_traits< RandomAccess >::difference_type k,
                       Compare comp )
{

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits< RandomAccess >::difference_type Int;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits< RandomAccess >::value_type      Val;

    if( first == last ) return false;
    Int n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (k > n) return false;

    //Int n = distance(first, last);
    //Int i = -1;

    RandomAccess i = last;
    for(RandomAccess j = first + k - 1;
        j >= first; --j)
    {
        if (std::max_element(j,last) != j)
        {
            i = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == last) return false;

    {    
        // Сначала ищем первый, больший p_[i]
        RandomAccess j = i;
        ++j;
        while(!comp(*i,*j)) ++j;
        RandomAccess imin = j; // Индекс минимального
        for(; j != last; ++j)
        {
            if (comp(*i,*j) &&
                comp(*j,*imin))
            {
                imin = j;
            }
        }
        std::swap( *i, *imin );
        ++i;
    }

    RandomAccess u = first + std::min(k,n-1);
    while ( i < u )
    {
        RandomAccess imin = i;
        for(RandomAccess j = i + 1; j != last; ++j)
        {
            if (comp(*j,*imin)) imin = j;
        }
        std::swap( *i, *imin );
        ++i;
    }

    return true;
}

template< typename RandomAccess >
bool next_kpermutation( RandomAccess first, RandomAccess last, int k )
{
    return ( next_kpermutation( first, last, k,
                               std::less< typename std::iterator_traits< RandomAccess >::value_type >( )
    ) );
}

static void alm_error(int) {}
static int alm_lex(void*qq,ALM_STYPE*alm_lval)
{
    const char *& alm_textpointer = *(const char **)qq;

    while(*alm_textpointer==' ' /*||*alm_textpointer=='\t' */) ++alm_textpointer;
    switch(*alm_textpointer)
    {
    case 0:   return EOF;
    case '0':
        {
            if (isdigit(*(alm_textpointer+1))) return Wrong;
        }
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        {
            *alm_lval = 0;
            while(*alm_textpointer >= '0' && *alm_textpointer <= '9')
            {
                *alm_lval = (*alm_lval)*10 + (*alm_textpointer - '0');
                ++alm_textpointer;
            }
            return Number;
        } break;
    case '*':
        if (*(alm_textpointer+1) == '*')
        {
            alm_textpointer += 2;
            return '^';
        }
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '/':
    case '=':
    case '^':
    case ';':
    case '!':
    case '#':
    case '%':
        {
            *alm_lval = 0;
            return *alm_textpointer++;
        } break;

    }
    ++alm_textpointer;
    return Wrong;
}

mutex mx;
int total_count = 0;

void almetis(int begin, int end,
             const char * buf, const char * symbols, int symno)
{
    char digs[] = "0123456789";
    int no = 0;
    do {
        if (no >= end) break;
        if (no < begin) continue;

        char stmt[2048];
        const char * c = buf;
        char *       t = stmt;
        for(;*c; ++c,++t)
        {
            switch(*c)
            {
            case ' ':
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '=':
            case '^':
            case ';':
            case '!':
            case '#':
            case '%':
            case '\t':
            case '\r':
            case '\n': *t = *c; break;
            default:
                for(int j = 0; j < symno; ++j)
                {
                    if (*c == symbols[j])
                    {
                        *t = digs[j];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        *t = 0;
        const char * q = stmt;
        if (alm_parse(&q) == 0)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
            total_count++;
            printf("%s\n",stmt);
        }
    } while(++no, next_kpermutation(digs,digs+10,symno));

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int threads = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if (threads <= 1) threads = 1;
    else if (threads > 6) threads = 6;
    printf("Threads: %d\n",threads);

    char buf[2048] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        strcat_s(buf,2048,argv[i]);
        if (i != argc-1) strcat_s(buf,2048," ");
    }

    char symbols[11] = { 0 };
    int symno = 0;
    for(const char * c = buf; *c; ++c)
    {
        if (strchr(" 01234567890()+-*/=^;#%!\t\r\n",*c)) continue;
        bool found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < symno; ++j)
            if (symbols[j] == *c)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        if (!found) symbols[symno++] = *c;
        if (symno == 11)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Too many symbols\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d symbols: %s\n",symno,symbols);

    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < symno; ++i) count *= (10-i);

    if ((count < 5000) || (threads == 1))
    {
        almetis(0,count,buf,symbols,symno);
    }
    else
    {
        int part = count / threads;
        assert(threads * part == count);

        vector<future<void>> fus;
        for(int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        {
            fus.push_back(async(almetis,i*part,(i+1)*part,buf,symbols,symno));
        }
        for(auto& x: fus) x.get();
    }
    printf("Solutions: %d\n",total_count);
}
static const int  alm_exca[] ={
    -1,      1,
                     0,     -1,
    -2,      0,
    };

#define   ALM_NPROD               22
#define   ALM_LAST               228
static const int  alm_act[]={

     9,    13,     4,     2,     9,    10,     1,    20,     8,    10,
     7,    21,     8,     0,     7,    33,    17,    15,    20,    16,
    20,    19,    21,     0,    21,    20,     0,    17,    15,    21,
    16,     0,    19,     5,    17,    15,    20,    16,     0,    19,
    21,     0,     0,     6,     0,    17,    14,    26,     0,     0,
    19,    22,    23,    24,    25,     0,     0,     0,    27,    28,
    29,    30,    31,    32,     0,     0,     0,     0,    18,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    18,
     0,    18,     0,     0,     0,     0,    18,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    18,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
     0,     3,    11,    12,     0,     0,    11,    12 };

static const int  alm_pact[]={

   -35, -1000, -1000, -1000,   -58, -1000,   -15,   -31,   -31,   -31,
   -31, -1000, -1000,   -31,   -31,   -31,   -31,   -31,   -31,   -31,
 -1000, -1000,   -13,   -13, -1000,   -26, -1000,    -8,     3,     3,
   -13,   -13,   -13, -1000 };

static const int  alm_pgo[]={

     0,     6,     3,     2,    33,    43 };

static const int  alm_r1[]={

     0,     1,     1,     2,     2,     3,     3,     4,     4,     5,
     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,
     5,     5 };

static const int  alm_r2[]={

     0,     1,     1,     1,     2,     3,     1,     3,     1,     3,
     3,     2,     2,     3,     3,     3,     2,     2,     2,     3,
     1,     1 };

static const int  alm_chk[]={

 -1000,    -1,    -2,   256,    -3,    -4,    -5,    45,    43,    35,
    40,   257,   258,    59,    61,    43,    45,    42,    94,    47,
    33,    37,    -5,    -5,    -5,    -5,    -4,    -5,    -5,    -5,
    -5,    -5,    -5,    41 };

static const int  alm_def[]={

     0,    -2,     1,     2,     3,     6,     8,     0,     0,     0,
     0,    20,    21,     4,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
    16,    17,    11,    12,    18,     0,     5,     7,     9,    10,
    13,    14,    15,    19 };

#define YACC_MEM_STACK
//#define  alm_IntError

#ifdef   alm_IntError
#define  alm_errNoMemory   -1
#define  alm_errStackOvr   -2
#define  alm_errSyntax     -3
#else
#define  alm_errNoMemory   "not enough memory"
#define  alm_errStackOvr   "internal stack overflow"
#define  alm_errSyntax     "syntax error"
#endif

#define ALM_FLAG    (-1000)
#define ALM_ERROR   goto alm_errlab
#define ALM_ACCEPT  return(0)
#define ALM_ABORT   return(1)

#if defined(YACC_MEM_HEAP)
template<typename T>
class alm__memory
{
    T * ptr_;
public:
    alm__memory(unsigned int size)
    {
        ptr_ = new T[size];
    };
    ~alm__memory()
    {
        delete[] ptr_;
    };
    T* ptr()
    {
        return ptr_;
    };
};
#endif

static int alm_parse( void * alm_param )
{
    ALM_STYPE   alm_lval = ALM_STYPE(), alm_val = ALM_STYPE();
    int      alm_char    = -1;
    int      alm_nerrs   =  0;
    int      alm_errflag =  0;
#if defined(YACC_MEM_HEAP)
    int    * alm_s;
    ALM_STYPE * alm_v;
#endif
#if defined(YACC_MEM_STACK)
    int      alm_s[ALM_MAXDEPTH+2];
    ALM_STYPE   alm_v[ALM_MAXDEPTH+2];
#endif
    int      alm_j, alm_m;
    ALM_STYPE * alm_pvt;
    int      alm_state, *alm_ps, alm_n;
    ALM_STYPE * alm_pv;
    const int    * alm_xi;

#if defined(YACC_MEM_HEAP)
    alm__memory<ALM_STYPE> ALM__M (ALM_MAXDEPTH+2);
    alm__memory<int  >  ALM__M1(ALM_MAXDEPTH+2);

    alm_v = ALM__M.ptr();
    alm_s = ALM__M1.ptr();

    if ((alm_v == NULL) || (alm_s == NULL))
    {
        alm_error(alm_errNoMemory);
        return(1);
    };
#endif

    alm_state     =  0;
    alm_char      = -1;
    alm_nerrs     =  0;
    alm_errflag   =  0;
    alm_ps        = &alm_s[-1];
    alm_pv        = &alm_v[-1];

alm_stack:
    if( ++alm_ps > &alm_s[ALM_MAXDEPTH] )
    {
        alm_error(alm_errStackOvr);
        return(1);
    }
    *alm_ps = alm_state;
    ++alm_pv;
    *alm_pv = alm_val;

alm_newstate:
    alm_n = alm_pact[alm_state];
    if( alm_n <= ALM_FLAG )
        goto alm_default;
    if( alm_char < 0 )
        if( (alm_char = (int  )alm_lex(alm_param,&alm_lval)) < 0 )
            alm_char = 0;
    if( (alm_n += alm_char) < 0 || alm_n >= ALM_LAST )
        goto alm_default;
    if( alm_chk[alm_n = alm_act[alm_n]] == alm_char )
    {
        alm_char  = -1;
        alm_val   = alm_lval;
        alm_state = alm_n;
        if( alm_errflag > 0 )
            --alm_errflag;
        goto alm_stack;
    }

alm_default:

    if( (alm_n = alm_def[alm_state]) == -2 )
    {
        if( alm_char < 0 )
            if( (alm_char = (int  )alm_lex(alm_param,&alm_lval)) < 0 )
                alm_char = 0;
        for(alm_xi=alm_exca; (*alm_xi!=(-1)) || (alm_xi[1]!=alm_state);alm_xi+=2)
            ;
        while( *(alm_xi += 2) >= 0 )
            if( *alm_xi == alm_char )
                break;
        if( (alm_n = alm_xi[1]) < 0 )
            return(0);
    }
    if( alm_n == 0 )
    {
        switch( alm_errflag )
        {
            case 0:
                alm_error(alm_errSyntax);
            alm_errlab:
                ++alm_nerrs;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                alm_errflag = 3;
                while ( alm_ps >= alm_s )
                {
                    alm_n = alm_pact[*alm_ps] + ALM_ERRCODE;
                    if( alm_n >= 0 && alm_n < ALM_LAST &&
                        alm_chk[alm_act[alm_n]] == ALM_ERRCODE )
                    {
                        alm_state = alm_act[alm_n];
                        goto alm_stack;
                    }
                    alm_n = alm_pact[*alm_ps];
                    --alm_ps;
                    --alm_pv;
                }
            alm_abort:
                return(1);
            case 3:
                if( alm_char == 0 )
                    goto alm_abort;
                alm_char = -1;
                goto alm_newstate;
        }
    }
    alm_ps -= alm_r2[alm_n];
    alm_pvt = alm_pv;
    alm_pv -= alm_r2[alm_n];
    alm_val = alm_pv[1];
    alm_m   = alm_n;
    alm_n   = alm_r1[alm_n];
    alm_j   = alm_pgo[alm_n] + *alm_ps + 1;
    if( alm_j >= ALM_LAST || alm_chk[alm_state = alm_act[alm_j]] != -alm_n )
        alm_state = alm_act[alm_pgo[alm_n]];
    switch(alm_m)
    {


case 1:{
               return alm_pvt[-0] ? 0 : -1;
           } break;
case 2:{
               return -1;
           } break;
case 3:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 4:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-1];
           } break;
case 5:{
               if (alm_pvt[-0] == 0) return -1;
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-2] && alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 6:{
               if (alm_pvt[-0] == 0) return -1;
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 7:{
               alm_val = (alm_pvt[-2] == alm_pvt[-0]) ? 1 : 0;
           } break;
case 8:{
               alm_val = (alm_pvt[-0] == 0) ? 1 : 0;
           } break;
case 9:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-2] + alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 10:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-2] - alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 11:{
               alm_val = -alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 12:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 13:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-2] * alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 14:{
               if (alm_pvt[-0] < 0) return -1;
               alm_val = 1;
               for(int i = 0; i < alm_pvt[-0]; ++i) alm_val *= alm_pvt[-2];
           } break;
case 15:{
               if (alm_pvt[-0] == 0) return -1;
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-2] / alm_pvt[-0];
               if (alm_val*alm_pvt[-0] != alm_pvt[-2]) return -1;
           } break;
case 16:{
               if (alm_pvt[-1] < 0) return -1;
               if (alm_pvt[-1] >=20) return -1;
               alm_val = fact(alm_pvt[-1]);
           } break;
case 17:{
               if (alm_pvt[-1] < 0) return -1;
               if (alm_pvt[-1] >=33) return -1;
               alm_val = bifact(alm_pvt[-1]);
           } break;
case 18:{
               if (alm_pvt[-1] < 0) return -1;
               alm_val = isqrt(alm_pvt[-0]);
               if (alm_val*alm_val != alm_pvt[-0]) return -1;
           } break;
case 19:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-1];
           } break;
case 20:{
               alm_val = alm_pvt[-0];
           } break;
case 21:{
               return -1;
           } break;

    }
    goto alm_stack;
}
```

Монстр, претендующий скорее на универсальность, чем на красоту. Поэтому по сравнению со специализированными программами, понятно, будет тормознее...

Тут - https://ideone.com/GHbA34 - переправленная для ввода из stdin версия. Кстати, почему-то работает на Ideone медленно, на моей машине исходное уравнение в 4 потока ковыряет примерно 0.25с (полное время работы программы).

Comment: Думаю, ideone даёт только одно ядро?

Comment: @Qwertiy Логично. Не подумал...

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на F#:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let sum1 = "VOLVO"
    let sum2 = "FIAT"
    let res = "MOTOR"

    let wordToInt(word : string, map : Map<char, int>) =
        word.ToCharArray() |> Array.map(fun ch -> map.[ch]) |> Array.reduce(fun n1 n2 -> n1 * 10 + n2)

    let checkSolution(map : Map<char, int>) =
        let s1 = wordToInt(sum1, map)
        let s2 = wordToInt(sum2, map)
        let resInt = s1 + s2
        let resNums = resInt.ToString().ToCharArray() |> Array.map(fun ch -> ch.ToString() |> int)
        if resNums.Length <> res.Length then
            List.empty
        else
            let pairs = res.ToCharArray() |> Array.mapi(fun i ch -> (resNums.[i], ch))
            let existingCharsFailed = pairs |> Array.exists(fun (num, ch) -> if map.ContainsKey(ch) then map.[ch] <> num else false)
            if existingCharsFailed then
                List.empty
            else
                let newChars = pairs |> Array.where(fun (num, ch) -> not(map.ContainsKey(ch)))
                if newChars |> Array.exists(fun (num1, ch1) -> newChars |> Array.exists(fun (num2, ch2) -> ch1 = ch2 && num1 <> num2)) then
                    List.empty
                else
                    if newChars |> Array.exists(fun (num1, ch2) -> map |> Map.exists(fun ch2 num2 -> num1 = num2)) then
                        List.empty
                    else
                        [(s1, s2)]

    let rec find(index : int, chs : char[], set : Set<int>, map : Map<char, int>) =
        if index < chs.Length then
            set |> Set.toList
                |> List.map(fun i -> find(index + 1, chs, set.Remove(i), map.Add(chs.[index], i)))
                |> List.reduce(fun sol1 sol2 -> sol1 @ sol2)
        else
            checkSolution(map)

    let summandChars = (sum1 + sum2).ToCharArray() |> Array.distinct
    let solutions = find(0, summandChars, set [0..9], Map.empty)

    for (s1, s2) in solutions |> List.sortBy(fun (s1, s2) -> s1) do
        printfn "%d+%d=%d" s1 s2 (s1 + s2)

    0
```

Comment: У меня за полторы секунды в linqpad отработало, неплохой результат.

Comment: Возможно вам будет интересно узнать о русскоязычном [F# сообществе](http://fsharplang.ru). Кроме этого в [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) есть канал для обсуждения F# на русском языке. Для того, чтобы туда попасть нужно  присоединиться к [F# Software Foundation](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join) и после этого вы должны получить приглашение в slack. Если возникнут какие-либо вопросы можете спросить у меня [F# чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на C# на массивах без Dictionary, возможно не очень понятный, зато быстрый.

Что бы перебрать все возможные перестановки используется цикл до общего их количества. Например, если у нас 6 символов, первый символ может быть любой (10 вариантов), для второго символа остается 9 вариантов, и т.д. Получается, количество перестановок равно: `10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5`.

Дальше цикл раскручивает число в перестановку. Массив `num` содержит цифры, которые остались для выбора. Он "обнуляется" каждый раз: `for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) num[j] = j;` Как только мы выбрали очередную цифру, она удаляется с массива: `for (int k = mapNum; k < depth; k++)`

Цифры выбираются как остатки от деления, сначала на 10, потом на 9 (так как остается только 9 цифр для выбора), и т.д.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sum1 = "VOLVO";
    string sum2 = "FIAT";
    string res = "MOTOR";

    char[] chars = (sum1 + sum2 + res).Distinct().ToArray();

    if (chars.Length > 10)
        Console.WriteLine("No solutions");
    else
    {
        int permutations = 1;
        for (int i = 11 - chars.Length; i <= 10; i++)
            permutations *= i;

        int[] map = new int[256];
        int[] num = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < permutations; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                num[j] = j;
            int depth = 10;
            int index = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < chars.Length; j++)
            {
                int mapNum = index % depth;
                map[chars[j]] = num[mapNum];
                index /= depth;
                depth--;
                for (int k = mapNum; k < depth; k++)
                    num[k] = num[k + 1];
            }

            int num1 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sum1.Length; j++)
                num1 = num1 * 10 + map[sum1[j]];
            int num2 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sum2.Length; j++)
                num2 = num2 * 10 + map[sum2[j]];
            int resn = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < res.Length; j++)
                resn = resn * 10 + map[res[j]];
            if (num1 + num2 == resn)
                Console.WriteLine($"{num1}+{num2}={resn}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Быстрый. И не основан на тех оптимизациях, которые я видел. Несложно пояснить в двух словах?

Comment: @AK Добавил объяснение. Пока писал, обнаружилась небольшая ошибка, которая не позволила бы выдавать корректный результат в общем случае.

Comment: О! Уловил идею. Да, это резко снижает число вариантов для перебора. Но я такое обычно на листочке сначала долго прорабатываю, это не простой перебор силой.

Answer (score 2):

```js
find(...parse("VOLVO + FIAT == MOTOR"));

function parse(expr) {
    var letters = [...new Set(expr.match(/\w/g))];
    var words = [...new Set(expr.match(/\w+/g))];
    
    var defs = words.map(w => `const ${w} = ` + 
     [...w].map((l, i) => `${l} * ${Math.pow(10, w.length - i - 1)}`).join(" + ")
    ).join("\n");
    var q1 = `function ([${letters.join(", ")}]) {
        ${defs}
        return ${expr};
    }`;
    var quotedExpr = "`" + expr.replace(/\w+/g, w => "${" + w + "}") + "`";
    var q2 = `function ([${letters.join(", ")}]) {
        ${defs}
        return ${quotedExpr};
    }`;
    return new Function (`return [${q1}, ${q2}]`)();
}

function find(pred, fn) {
  const digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  do {
    if (pred(digits))
     console.log(fn(digits));

    let i;
    for (i = 1; i < digits.length; i++)
      if (digits[i-1] < digits[i])
        break;

    if (i == digits.length) break;

    let j;
    for (let k = 0; k<i; k++)
      if (digits[k] < digits[i]) {
        j = k;
        break;
      }

    [digits[j], digits[i]] = [digits[i], digits[j]];
    i--;
    for (j = 0; j<i; j++, i--) {
      [digits[i], digits[j]] = [digits[j], digits[i]];
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на C#:

```
void Main()
{
    var word1 = "VOLVO";
    var word2 = "FIAT";
    var word3 = "MOTOR";

    var letters = string.Concat(word1,word2,word3).Distinct();

    var distinctLetters = letters.Count();
    if( distinctLetters > 10)
        return;

    var minNum = (int)Math.Pow(10, distinctLetters-1);
    var maxNum = (int)Math.Pow(10, distinctLetters) - 1;

    for(var i = minNum; i < maxNum; i++)
    {
        var dict = MakeDict(letters, i);

        if(!IsEnabled(dict))
            continue;

        if(!IsSuitable(word1, word2, word3, dict))
            continue;

        dict.Dump();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

bool IsSuitable(string word1, string word2, string word3, Dictionary<char, int> dict)
{
    int a1 = Convert(word1, dict);
    int a2 = Convert(word2, dict);
    int a3 = Convert(word3, dict);

    return a1 + a2 == a3;
}

int Convert(string word, Dictionary<char, int> dict)
{
    var j = word.Length;
    int result = 0;
    foreach (var element in word)
    {
        int pos = dict[element];
        result +=  pos * (int)Math.Pow(10, j);
        j--;
    }
    return result;
}

bool IsEnabled(Dictionary<char,int> data)
{
    // Каждая цифра может быть закреплена только за одной буквой
    return data.Select(x => x.Value)
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
               .All(x => x.Count == 1);
}

Dictionary<char, int> MakeDict(IEnumerable<char> source, int num)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    string a = num.ToString();
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        var curChar = int.Parse(a.Substring(i, 1));
        result.Add(element, curChar);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Уже после написания вижу, что можно сделано неоптимальнее и можно ещё разгонять во многих местах.

Просто оставлю как базовую версию на c#, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: Вообще, для начала надо полностью выкорчевать Dictionary<char, int> - достаточно только int  (меняется в цикле) и distinctLetters (который не меняется). Заодно и linq в IsEnabled уйдёт.